# joomla component with jquery and ajax error response

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla2.5

Without AJAX I would output errors to the user like so (usually in the controller):

```
JError::raiseWarning( 100, JText::_('COM_EXAMPLE_EXCEED_LIMIT') ); // or: jexit(JText::_('COM_EXAMPLE_EXCEED_LIMIT'));      
//then redirect them back to component
JFactory::getApplication()->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_example'));
```

With AJAX you can't do this as it will just fail to parse whatever data your sending back (in my case json)

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "index.php?option=com_example&task=add",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data){
    //do stuff
    }
});
```

Ideally I'd like to use `JError::raiseWarning` because it is nice and pretty. But not sure that is possible since that is server side and the response is coming client side? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to fill the element with the id `system-message-container` with your error message using Javascript. However it may fail depending on the template if it uses an override.

If you really need a message like from JError, you need to reload the page and generate it on serverside. But the point of AJAX is that you don't reload the page :-)

Also note that JError is depreceated. Use `$app->enqueueMessage('message', 'type')` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. `system-message-container` is very good to know! I've decided to go with a JSON error message on success. Not the prettiest, but I don't think there really is an elegant way.